# How to set es.nodes parameter to multiple Elasticsearch nodes for Spark ?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, elasticsearch-hadoop

So I want to read data from multiple Elasticsearch nodes into Spark. I prefer to use the "es.nodes" parameter and set "es.nodes.discovery" to false. The configuration parameters are described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html). I tried to find some example on how to set "es.nodes" to an array of values but I couldn't. Help please.

Comment: es.nodes property can be set as the following : `"machine1:port1,machine2:port2"`

Comment: could you tell me how to alias two nodes ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use this :

```
passthrough {
es.nodes.discovery: false
es.nodes: "foobar:9200"
}
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: Please it is good to add more explanation on your answer. Like where to add this code? Is there a file to edit ? Is there a file to create ? where ? This will be helpful

Comment: @JosephTankoua Yes, makes sense and you are correct there should be more explanation but I guess within the question, everything has already explained and description of the question has links where these settings can be added. I will try to add more description and thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @arglee very nice of you